# subsequences with the greatest number of matches?

Tags: c#, algorithm, haskell

Given an 2d array of data, how would I find the largest combination with the most matches?

Example:

```
Cust #  Prod #
C1      P1
C1      P2
C2      P1
C2      P3
C3      P1
C3      P3
C3      P4
```

(using haskell - couldn't figure out how do this easily in C# which is desired)
The subsequences are:

```
    > subsequenc­es ["P1"­,"P2","P3"­, "P4"]­
    => [[],["P1"],["P2"],["P1","P2"],["P3"],["P1","P3"],["P2","P3"],["P1","P2","P3"],["P4"],["P1","P4"],["P2","P4"],["P1","P2","P4"],["P3","P4"],["P1","P3","P4"],["P2","P3","P4"],["P1","P2","P3","P4"]]
```

I want to find the a subsequence of X size with more than Y matches...

So for this example, the largest subsequence with more than one match is: ["P1", "P3"] - with 2 counts

Because the individual customer sequences are:

```
    C1 => ["P1, "P2"]
    C2 => ["P1", "P3"]
    C3 => ["P1", "P3", "P4"]
```

So there are two instances of ["P1", "P3"] in those sets.

My initial thought was to generate the subsequences and then match, but my data set is too large.

**Note**: My data set has 13000 unique combinations of 2D data so the subsequence approach either overflowed or never finished depending on the language.

**EDIT**: I am interested in the longest subset (not ordered)

**EDIT**: @Jimmy: if you add the following to your list I would have expected to see P1, P2, P4 as the result since it has the most customers with that basket. Your solution unfortunately does not work

```
    { "C4", new HashSet<string>(new[] { "P1", "P2","P4"})},
    { "C5", new HashSet<string>(new[] { "P1", "P2","P4"})},
    { "C6", new HashSet<string>(new[] { "P1", "P2","P4"})},
```

**EDIT**: @Eric Lippert

My ideal output would be every combination and every time it was a subset. I could then do a query of the largest baskets with a minimum number of goods in that basket.

**EDIT**: To put into a business perspective, I want to find  the most frequently occurring basket of goods that many of my customers purchase. I realize many and size of basket is vague - but that's where the analysis of the result comes in.

Comment: So just to clarify the question a bit: you have n sequences, and you wish to assign each possible subsequence a ranking, based on how many of those n sequences are a match to the subsequence? I notice that your question is ill-posed because you are trying to optimize for two different things without saying how to balance them. There are three instances of the subsequence "P1" (in C1, C2 and C3). Why is then the subsequence "P1, P3" better, which only appears in two?  How do you balance "more appearances" vs "longer"?

Comment: Further clarification: Are you sure you are concerned about sub **sequences** or are you in fact concerned about sub **sets**. That is, does the order in which P1, P2, P3, P4 appear matter? Sequences are by definition ordered: (P1, P2) is different than (P2, P1). Sets are by definition unordered. Finding longest common subsequence is a very different problem than finding largest common subset.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question for clarity.
Do you want to find 
 1)  Sequence with maximum frequency  OR
 2)  Longest sequence

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be formulated as below (If I understand you well) :

*Given n sets : C1 ... CN ,* 
*each composed of element {P1 ... PN}*

*Find an intersection set of X of these subset with at least Y elements .*

The more complexe problem of **finding the maximum subset intersection of these N sets is NP-Hard** (cf this [proof](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~popa/ipl.pdf) ) .

Your problem might be NP-Hard as well or NP-complete (since it looks like the decisional version of the problem of finding the maximum intersection). You will not be able to find an efficient solution to your problem.

You should look up for heuristic of the maximum subset intersection problem or find inspiration looking at some similar (but different ) and more popular problems such as the set-covering problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is similar to this 
1 a | 1 b | 1 c

2 a | 2 b

3 c | 3 d

Which is equivalent of

abc | ab | cd

So basically the problem you are trying to solve has to be either
 1. Find maximum length string
 2. Find string with with maximum frequency
 3. Combination thereof

Represent the series as vector, write a custom comparison function for that vector, add them to multiset, while keeping count.  AND remember the largest count encountered so far for most frequent sequence and also remember longest vector inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Answering only the longest subsequence :

```
customer c = entryList[0].customer;
product p;
set s;
set largestSet = s;
for (every entry in entryList)
{
  if(c ! = entry.customer)
   {  
     c = entry.customer;
     if (s.size > largestSet.size)    largestSet = s;
     s.clear();
   }

   s.add(entry.customer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the longest pairwise subset.

This is a brute-force way to do it:

Starting from a list of tuples (c,p), make a dictionary of {c:set(p1,p2,p3)}.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> {
    { "C1", new HashSet<string>(new[] { "P1", "P2"})},
    { "C2", new HashSet<string>(new[] { "P1", "P3"})},
    { "C3", new HashSet<string>(new[] { "P1", "P3","P4"})},
};
var max = from pair1 in dict
          from pair2 in dict
          where pair2.Key != pair1.Key
          let s = pair1.Value.Intersect(pair2.Value).ToArray()
          orderby s.Length descending
          select s;

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", max.First()));
```

---

Outputs:

```
P1,P3
```

Seems like an O(N^3) algorithm.